# IdentityServer4 Configuration Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I am adding IdentityServer4 to an .net core 2.1 app and am having issues with signing out and it is making thing that I have an overall structure issue.

From all examples I can find Clients have a different RedirectUris and PostLogoutRedirectUris port than what their options.Authority is.

For example my cleints are:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client> {
            new Client {
                ClientId = "oauthClient",
                ClientName = "Example Client Credentials Client Application",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret> {
                        new Secret("superSecretPassword".Sha256())},
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> {"customAPI.read"}
                },
            new Client {
                ClientId = "openIdConnectClient",
                ClientName = "Example Implicit Client Application",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "role",
                    "customAPI.write"
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:5000"}
            }
        };
    }
```

and my IdentityServer is set up as

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("cookie")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
                options.ClientId = "openIdConnectClient";
                options.SignInScheme = "cookie";
            });
```

think this is wrong but I am not sure, when I set `options.Authority = "http://localhost:5001/";` which is what I think I should do from my examples I get an exception.

This may be a dumb question but can I use IdentityServer4 with only 1 host, or do I need two?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding your question, but I'll try to answer to the best of my ability.

You can configure identity server and the project your using with identity server on the same host.

That being said, it really depends on what your intent is. For example, should the identity server be available if the client application is down?

Comment: I apologize for my generality I am just trying to pick up IdentityServer and having issues getting it to work. But yes I have a UI and an API, so identity should be running for the API even if no one is using the UI.